# React Otp Input onChange not getting called on entering input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact, react-otp-input

I am using [react-otp-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-otp-input), in a preact application. I have written the following code ,

```
const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
<OtpInput
  value={otp}
  onChange={(value) => {
      console.log(value);
      setOtp(value);
  }}
  placeholder={'12121'}
  numInputs={5}
  containerStyle={'otp-container'}
  inputStyle={'otp-input'}
  errorStyle={'otp-error'}
  hasErrored={otpError}
  />
```

When I am input any value from keyboard the otp is not getting updated i.e `onChange` is not getting called, but when I hit `backspace`, the `onChange` is getting called.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Anil, I don't see any issue in above code. I tried it in sandbox, state is getting updated. https://codesandbox.io/s/test-react-sandbox-forked-5y9yk6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yeah, it is working fine in standalone environment, but in my project, it is not the same. As mentioned in the https://github.com/devfolioco/react-otp-input/issues/110, the same thing is happening.

Comment: We have resolved this bug, Please use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react18-input-otp to get OTP inputs.